# The listing in web pages, how it can solve ?

Tags: lists

I have more than 50 links in Medicine Category  and I need to list them but don't want to show them all at once. because the main content of the page become under the fold .

Initially I display 6 links and include a link to the rest ("more"), so when the user clicks on "more" a pop-up screen appears with all the links.

I'm not happy with this approach, can anyone suggest a better way to list all the links?
or any one can give me some example form sites Contains a big list of links!

Comment: Is there any way of subdividing the links into related groups? As you imply, 50 links is a lot to show at once.

Comment: What is the nature of your site?

Comment: I strongly suggest you avoid using popups. "to display 6 links and but link more" – What do you mean here? Rephrase perhaps?

Comment: mmmm ... i can't subdividing the links into related groups because i have some category Contains just 4 - 7 links . if i subdividing the Medicine Category and not do the same to the all category it will be a weird behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to show all the single elements there? For Usability's sake, nobody will effectively scan and find something in 60 items.

If you got this requirement from your SEO-Guy (to push internal crosslinks) you may as well think about a fat footer (http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/FatFooter), where you can put all the items whithout annoying the user.

If you need all the items in the one menu anyway, you might try out something like this:

- Single Menu-Item "Medicines"
- on click: drops out a big big canvas which takes a lot of width-space
- the link-items are ordered! by alphabet while having a A-B-C Caption (to make quick scanning easier)
- each row-height is limited (i.e. max 10 items per Caption, 2 Caption-blocks in one colum)
- if they are STILL too much items, create a "more" button within the menu, which expands the menu to almost-fullscreen size, so all items can be displayed.

[image]

Comment: hmmm... i think this is the best for me :) it make quick scanning easier, i will go with this.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't add subcategories to the Medicine category as you mention in the comments, maybe you can still "cheat" and present this as top-level categories. I mean that instead of subdividing in form of

```
Medicine
          Subcategory A
          Subcategory B
          Subcategory C
```

You could go with

```
Medicine A 
Medicine B
Medicine C
```

Answer (score 0):

I would begin asking the purpose of the links - is it part of the content? does it trigger any application. The approach if would take is to include a more link that would expand on clicking within the page. call it progressive disclosure.

The other way is to divided the page content area itself into two sections. Let one section just include all the links while the other section displays content.

I prefer the first method of displaying the more link.